# Movie which includes a scene where a man gets bugged by red winged devils / demons

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, stop-motion-animation

I need your help to find a specific movie for my best friend. As a child somewhere around the end of the 80's or the beginning of the 90's he saw a certain scene on TV that scared the hell out of him back then and he still remembers it to this day. Unfortunately he doesn't know what movie or TV movie it was and even years later when he saw that scene again, he didn't memorize the title :D

So here are all the info we have in regard to that movie:

- The scene: In a modern day city setting a guy (real person) enters a dark room - perhaps a factory or a (storage) hall - and after a few minutes little (perhaps 1,5 feet / 50 cm tall) red winged devils or demons animated in stop-motion (!) start to fly around him while bugging him at the same time.
- From his second encounter with this scene my friend remembers that the movie was some sort of a silly horror comedy, which confused him a little cause that wasn't what he had experienced back in the 80's or 90's :D Also back then it ran during the afternoon which means it can't be harder than a PG-13 movie.
- Regarding the scene it reminds me very much of the "Jim Henson's The Storyteller" episode "The Soldier and Death", but he says it's not it.

We already tried a few things to find it, but so far nothing led to the right movie. Perhaps you guys know which movie it could be, cause after I had the chance to relive my childhood trauma "The Gate" a few years ago it's now finally time for him to relive his too. :D

Answer (score 3):

They're not red, but might you be referring to Waxflatter's death in the 1985 *[Young Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Sherlock_Holmes)*? He's seemingly attacked by two imp statues that animated before his eyes, and fly around him, burrowing up his coat. He dies when he tries to stab them and instead stabs himself.

### Waflatter's death

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the scene my friend has in mind. He says that those two imps come close to the red creatures in regards to their size and look, but according to his memory they were bright red and could talk and the scene took place in a modern 80's / 90's setting. Despite calling it a silly horror comedy in my first post it could also be an adventure or action movie with fantasy elements like for example "The Golden Child" or "Big Trouble in Little China".
It's not much but one thing he also remembers is that the person enters the scene from the right side of the frame through a door.